# How do we use the word "landfall" in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

May I ask for a specific sentence using the word **"landfall"**?

> > which has a definition of: *a reaching of land as by a traveler, craft, or storm* according to the Merriam-Webster Dictionary.
> >
> > according to this Dictionary, one of the examples of the use of this word is as follows: *"From the deck of the boat, we saw our first landfall."*

Despite this, however, I did not know how to use it in other sentence formats, such as in this sample sentence: *It will soon make a landfall in Japan.*

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: _Landfall_ is a **noun**, not an adjective.

Comment: I once read this, though: _"We've got to make our landfall at the Lodge while it's still daylight."_  (by Jenkins, Geoffrey A DAYSTAR OF FEAR) which is quite similar to the aforementioned sentence. In both sentences, **landfall** is being used as a noun. I'm sorry if I was implying it as an adjective.

Comment: It is an expression used by sailors. It would be rather funny if you would use it today in normal language. Oald says, literary http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/landfall?q=landfall

Comment: @rogermue: it's an expression that applies to ships and hurricanes, but it's perfectly suitable for normal language in those contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*Hurricanes of the North Atlantic: Climates and Society*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PCzEjOjX8zYC&pg=PA383&dq=%22landfall%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAzgUahUKEwj9npHWlt_GAhWMe5IKHW4NDQE#v=onepage&q=%22landfall%22&f=false) by James B. Elsner and A. Birol Kara:

> Technically, hurricane **landfall** occurs when all or part of the
>   hurriane eye wall crosses the coastline.

Answer (score 2):

> It will soon make a landfall in Japan

I suspect it should be without the "a".

I think sailors normally say "make landfall": e.g. "We expect to make landfall at noon."